# How do I get a listbox to multiselect and concatenate string answers? C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, multi-select

I’m trying to get the listbox to return the strings concatenated and comma separated, returned as a string.

In my ViewModel I have:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> XListItems
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "A", Text = "A" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "B", Text = "B" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "C", Text = "C" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "D", Text = "D" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "E", Text = "E" });
            return list;
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel also contains a log which contains AString, which is a String.

In my view I have:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.log.AString, Model.XListItems, new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

Right now it is just returning the first item that is selected.

How would I allow the user to select multiple items and have them be returned as a string, such as: "A, C, D"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to return a comma separated string (you would need javascript to construct it). Just change the property `AString` in you model to `string[] AString {get; set;}`. The property will then contain an array of the values that have been selected.

If you do need to save the values in that format, then use (in the POST method)

```
var result = string.Join(",", AString);
```

And you do not need to include `new {Multiple = "multiple"})`. `ListBoxFor` will add that attribute anyway.